# Magento2 Subtotal Displaying Wrongly Based on Country

Tags: magento2, tax, subtotal

When i added a product to cart which is 136.35 cost , If `india` is shipping destination under shopping cart Estimation Shipping And tax block then it is showing subtotal finely. But if you selected `United States` as the destination then it is showing subtotal as 101 . How can we get same cost of all countries except shipping prices.

Attaching my configurations for tax caluculations.

[image: tax caluculation settings]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: When i removed all tax classes everything works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Get the calculations correct for all countries we had an option in the Admin Panel .

Go To `Stores > Configurations > Sales > Tax` , In the Calculation Settings you need to select `'Yes'` to `'Enable Cross Border Trade'` option.
[image]